# MarkerCluster markers are still showing behind cluster

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to hide the markers behind my cluster and only have them show when the marker is clicked.

This is how it appears:

[image: This is how it appears. However when I click the cluster and exit it, it goes back to how it should look (second pic)]

However when I click the cluster and exit it, it goes back to how it should look (second pic)

[image: This is how I want it to look originally]

(This is how I want it to look originally)

This is my code:

```js
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();



 

   
                        markers.addLayer(L.marker([currentLatitude, currentLongitude], { icon: populationIcon }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(
                            `The population of ${thisCountry.countryName} is ${thisCountry.countryPopulation}.`));


                        markers.addLayer(capitalMarker = L.marker([currentLatitude, currentLongitude], { icon: cityIcon }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(
                            `The capital city of ${thisCountry.countryName} is ${thisCountry.countryCapital}.`));

                        markers.addLayer(carMarker = L.marker([currentLatitude, currentLongitude], { icon: carIcon }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(
                            `They drive on the ${thisCountry.carSide} of the road in ${thisCountry.countryName}.`));

                        //add cluster to map
                        mymap.addLayer(markers);
```

Comment: Please refrain from adding a new issue to your initial question. Making it a separate question as you have done is the appropriate action indeed. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the created marker to the map too and this is wrong (`icon: carIcon }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(`).

Change

```
 markers.addLayer(carMarker = L.marker([currentLatitude, currentLongitude], { icon: carIcon })
  .addTo(mymap)
  .bindPopup(`They drive on the ${thisCountry.carSide} of the road in ${thisCountry.countryName}.`));
```

to

```
 markers.addLayer(carMarker = L.marker([currentLatitude, currentLongitude], { icon: carIcon })
  .bindPopup(`They drive on the ${thisCountry.carSide} of the road in ${thisCountry.countryName}.`));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I am now trying to add a second cluster to my map, however it is hiding behind the first so you can't see it - do you know how to fix this? :) (will post code below)

Comment: @TamsinVaz as far as I know, you can't show both markerclusters on the same place at same time. One is always behinde the other. But you can control with `.bringToFron()` which cluster is above. Please post a new question and accept my answer :)